# With QEMU/KVM, I get a poor display quality with a linux guest and host

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, kvm, qemu, display

I'm new to QEMU/KVM. I've created a new VM with the GUI (Virtual Machine Manager) and installed in it Kubuntu 14.04 (my host is Kubuntu 17.04). The quality of the display of the guest is very poor. Moreover, I can't switch to full screen, and the option "auto resize VM with window" is grayed out. The video model is QXL. What should I do to fix that?

Comment: Do you use the xorg qxl driver inside the guest? Are you connecting using a spice client?

Comment: I don't know which driver I use in the guest. How do I check it? It seems like I use spice, whatever that is, because in the Virtual Machine Manager there are hardware components named "Display Spice" and "Channel spice". I didn't do anything special neither in the host nor in the guest, I just created the VM in the Virtual Machine Manager with the default settings and installed the guest OS as I would on a physical machine.

Comment: Try this article: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_debug_Xorg_problems#What_driver_am_I_using.3F

Comment: Ok I found in `journalctl -e` a line containing `initialized qxl` so I guess it's using qxl.

Comment: That means QXL has been initialized. Do you have xorg-x11-drv-qxl installed?

Comment: It's not. However, when I try to install it, I get dependency problems. It says it depends on `xorg-video-abi-15` and `xserver-xorg-core`, however doesn't seem to propose any reasonable way to resolve the dependency problems without removing dozens of packages.

Comment: Looks like we might have found the problem

Comment: Yes, but how to solve the dependency hell? :)

Comment: I think that would be a separate question

Comment: Ok, and the answer would be? I disagree that opening a separate question for this specific qxl dependency problem is appropriate.

Comment: You may agree or disagree, but this is a QnA site, questions and answers, not much else. If you want to solve a dependency issue, ask about it, and maybe then it will solve this issue too (or it may not). Ihiye beseder, Yaron ;)

Comment: It's exactly that kind of redundant principal arguments as the one you've just created that often make me not want to come back here. I wish you all the best.

Comment: Enjoy your self righteousness when you troubleshoot. It will definitely help.